What is the action of $O(k)$ on $V_k(\mathbb R^n)$ making it a principal bundle?
Let $V_k(\mathbb R^n)$ be the Stiefel manifold of ordered $k$-tuples of vectors in $\mathbb R^n$.  I have seen in many places that $V_k(\mathbb R^n)$ is an $O(k)$ principal bundle over the Grassmanian $Gr_k(\mathbb R^n)$, but what is the smooth free right action of $O(k)$ on $V_k(\mathbb R^n)$?\
In particular, let $(v_1,\dots, v_k)\in V_k(\mathbb R^n)$, and let $W$ be the vector space that it span. An element $g\in O(k)$ should take the frame $(v_1,\dots, v_k)$ to another frame for $W$, but I do not see how to do this in a smooth way. First, since $W\subset \mathbb R^n$, we need a representation of $O(k)$ on $\mathbb R^n$ for elements to act on any $W\subset \mathbb R^n$, as otherwise we would be choosing a new representation for each fibre, and that doesn't sound smooth at all to me. However, if we fix a representation of $O(k)$ on $\mathbb R^n$ we no longer have that $g\cdot W=W$ which is exactly what we need for $V_k(\mathbb R^n)$ to be a principal bundle over $Gr_k(\mathbb R^n)$.
Indeed, consider the case where $O(2)$ acts on $\mathbb R^3$ by:
\begin{align}
\begin{pmatrix}
\cos \theta&0&\sin\theta\\
0&1&0\\
-\sin\theta&0&\cos\theta
\end{pmatrix}
\end{align}
then if $(e_1,e_2)\in V_2(\mathbb R^3)$, we have that $g\in O(k)$ takes $(e_1,e_2)$ to
$(e_1\cos\theta -e_3\sin\theta,e_2)$, which don't span the subpsace at all.
So what should the action be?

A point of $V_k(\mathbb{R}^n)$ is an orthonormal $k$-frame of $\mathbb{R}^n$. You put these vectors into a matrix $A\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times k}$ and the orthonormality condition simply becomes $A^tA=1_k$. The right action of $O(k)$ on $V_k(\mathbb{R}^n)$ is now given by right multiplication of matrices. It might  be conceptually clearer to equivalently think of an orthonormal $k$-frame as a linear isometric embedding $\mathbb{R}^k\hookrightarrow\mathbb{R}^n$ and the group $O(k)$ as the group of linear isometries of $\mathbb{R}^k$. In this case, the action is simply given by precomposition, which makes it clear this is a well-defined action.

I did some thinking and thought that each point $p\in V_k(\mathbb R^k)$ determines a linear isomorphism $A_p:W\rightarrow \mathbb R^k$, so $gA_p:W\rightarrow \mathbb R^k$ is a new frame for $W$. I turn this into a right action by saying that $p\cdot g=g^{-1}\cdot p=g^{-1}A_p$. Is this equivalent to your second statement or have I messed up?

Oh wait, $A_p$ is an isomorphism $\mathbb R^k\rightarrow W$, so I want to precompose giving me a right action as desired. This makes much more sense.

Yes, you got it now. The isomorphism sends the $k$-th standard basis vector to the $k$-th element of the frame.

Great Thank you!
